# Loading all widget assests with a single call?

Tags: jquery, css, loading

I'm wondering if it's at all possible (either natively or through plug-ins) to make a single call to a URL and have it return both the CSS and the JS files for a single widget. This is assuming that I have control of both the request and the response of such a request.

Would this be possible (and if so, how) or am I just overly optimistic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the request? You can just add the stylesheet / JS file dynamicly.

```
// The JS
$.getScript("http://www.domain.com/script.js", function(){
    alert("SCRIPT LOADED");
});

// The CSS
var url = "http://www.domain.com/style.css";
$('head').append( '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + url + '" />' );
```

Other ways:

1. Do a ajax call and add the JS to the head like the CSS is done above.